# INotifyPropertyChanged doesn`t update UI(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

The problem is that the binding of ViewModel properties to the control`s properties does not work correctly. I checked the properties and their values ​​change, but the visibility of the controls does not change. Any idea what is involved in this? Or am I missing something?

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
    Notifier notifier = new Notifier();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    }
    private Visibility mdiPanelVisibility=Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility MDIPanelVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return mdiPanelVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            mdiPanelVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MDIPanelVisibility");
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand showMDIPanelCommand;
    public RelayCommand ShowMDIPanelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return showMDIPanelCommand ??
                (showMDIPanelCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    MDIPanelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }));
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand hideMDIPanelCommand;
    public RelayCommand HideMDIPanelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return hideMDIPanelCommand ??
                (hideMDIPanelCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    MDIPanelVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                }));
        }
    }
    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and View:

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding MDIPanelVisibility}">
        <Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding HideMDIPanelCommand}"/>
        </Border.InputBindings>
    </Border>
    <ContentPresenter Width="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2" Panel.ZIndex="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding MDIPanelVisibility}">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <local:MDIView/>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <Button Content="Личный кабинет" FontSize="13" Command="{Binding ShowMDIPanelCommand}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource aLogButton}"/>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MainViewModel` class needs to inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which your class does not, in order for the binding framework to behave as expected when the view's `DataContext` is set to the `MainViewModel` instance.

Update class definition

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    //...
}
```